# Issues using strlen() to save a five letter string

Tags: c, file-io

I made this little program to get all the five letter words from a large text file containing all English words. I was wondering why I have set strlen(word)==6 instead of 5, even after i strtok "\n". My friend said I might have an issue with EOL conversions. I was reading about them but I can't understand them very well.

Let me know if I'm missing anything you might need to help me. Any suggestions to improve my code would be welcome as well. This is my first post so please bear with me. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 6

void manFile(char in_file[], char out_file[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    manFile("words_alpha.txt", "fiveletterwords.txt");
}

void manFile(char in_file[], char out_file[])
{
    FILE*inFp= fopen(in_file, "r");
    FILE*outFp= fopen(out_file, "w");

    char word[20];

    if(!inFp)
    {
        printf("File not opened.");
    }

    else
    {
        while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), inFp))
        {
            strtok(word, "\n");
            
            if(strlen(word)==SIZE)
            {
                fprintf(outFp,"%s\n", word);
            }
        }

        printf("File saved...");

        fclose(inFp);
        fclose(outFp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is it printing out 5 letter words when it should be printing out 6 letter words? Or vice versa? Do you see an extra blank line after every line of output? Without sample output (or input) its hard to tell what the actual issue is. If you could include the actual output and the expected output, that would be great.

Comment: Note that `strlen()` counts the length of the string excluding the null terminating byte.  To store a word with 5 letters, you must have at least 6 bytes to store it in.  It isn't clear that you are running into problems with that; you're using `char word[20]`.  Also, `fgets()` reads lines regardless of word boundaries; you'd use `fscanf(inFp, "%19s", word)` (the off-by-one is an unfortunate but unchangeable historical artefact) to skip white space, read up to 19 non-space characters and store the null byte to terminate the string.

Comment: You should show some sample input along with the expected output.  This is an important part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: If you want to remove a trailing newline, `strtok()` is an unusual choice.... I usually suggest `word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = 0;` (or maybe `*(strchrnul(word, '\n')) = 0;` if you have that non-standard function available.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. I solved it now but I will remember that for the next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on a windows-based system, line are terminated with both a newline ('\n') and a carriage-return ('\r'), so you probably want:

```
strtok(word,"\n\r");
```

Comment: stdio will convert between CRLF in the file and LF in the program, unless the file is opened in binary mode.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem, I'm running on my mac though.

Comment: The data may have come from a Windows system.